# CakePHP how to display related information

Tags: cakephp

My order table includes customer filed , When add new order, after choose the customer name from dropdown list, I want the same page to display the information of customer, for example, address, phone number from customer table

How to do? 
Thanks in advance...

Could you give me an example or related links? I don't know anything about AJAX, have no idea where to start.

Maybe this link: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp, but it uses php not cakephp...

the code in example is : xmlhttp.open("GET","**getuser.php?q="+str**,true);
I don't know how to pass customer_id(q=str) to orderscontroller/getuser function.need help

Comment: do you know javascript or jquery?

Comment: Could someone give me an example, I searched 4 hours and got nothing...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JsHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#jshelper) to achieve the same you mentioned. Kindly try at your end, and provide some raw code so that peers can help you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this

```
function showCustomer(str)
{
 var xmlhttp;
 if (str=="")
 {
   document.getElementById("divtoDisplayInfo").innerHTML="";
  return;
 }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("divtoDisplayInfo").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
 xmlhttp.open("GET","/yoursite/controllername/action/str,true); //if you use redirect and windows environment
 xmlhttp.send();
}
```

you should expect the view of that action so do the normal cake processing, get data in the controller, render view, if there is an error set the actions autorender to false.

but i will just advice you to download Jquery add to your cakephp framework this simple line

```
$("divToDisplayInfo's_ID").load("Controllername/action")
```

solves your problem.

Comment: I think you should add you solution here and mark as resolved that is the whole point of the forum i guess.